# Static Method vs Instance Method applied to an example

Tags: java, static-methods, instance-methods

Given this class

```
  public class Worker
private String name;
private static int WorkerCount = 0; // number of workers

public Worker(<*parameter list* >)
{
<*initialization of private instances variables* >
Worker++; //increment count of all worker
}

}
```

If I were to add the method...

```
public static int getWorkerCount()
{
return WorkerCount;}
```

How is the method I just added static instead of instance?
I think it can be an instance method as it operates on the **individual object** of "WorkerCount" which is originally equal to 0.

Comment: If it was non-static and the only place where the value gets updated is in the constructor like shown in your code, then the employeeCount value will always be 1, which is probably not what you are after.

Comment: It's static because it is not related to a specific instance of `Employee`.

Comment: `employeeCount` being an "individual object" is not the point as much as whether it is shared by all instances of the class as a field of the class itself or a field distinct to each instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method should be static to allow the employee count to be accessible at the class level.

Since `employeeCount` variable is static, the method body is already setup for this functionality. You likely want it this way as it keeps count of the total number of `Employee` objects initialized with that constructor.

Also notable is that `employeeCount` is a primitive value (an int), and shouldn't be referred to as an object.

Comment: is consistency something that programmers seek to maintain?

Comment: @CrazyRaisans, edited for clarity, highlighted accessibility at the class level as a better reason than consistency with the private static variable.

Comment: can void instance methods exist?

Answer (score 2):

It's more a question of *who* should be able to call method rather than how many objects it accesses, etc.

`static` fields and method belong to the *Class* rather than a particular *instance*. Thus no matter how many times you instantiate `Employee`, there will be exactly one `int employeeCount`. Each employee's reference to the `employeeCount` field goes back to the same location. By your use of the employeeCount field, you already get this, it's just a matter of applying the same logic to methods.

By making `getEmployeeCount()` static, you're saying that not only can any employee call it, the `Employee` class itself can call the method; you don't need an instance in order to call the method.

```
Employee.getEmployeeCount(); //Valid, because getEmployeeCount() is static
Employee.name; //Invalid (non-static reference from static context) because *which* employee's name?
```

Because it is only accessing static fields, this makes sense. No matter what instance you were to call it on, it would return the same value. Consider the code:

```
Employee a = new Employee();
Employee b = new Employee();

System.out.println(a.getEmployeeCount()); //2
System.out.println(b.getEmployeeCount()); //2
System.out.println(Employee.getEmployeeCount()); //2

Employee c = new Employee();

System.out.println(a.getEmployeeCount()); //3
System.out.println(b.getEmployeeCount()); //3
System.out.println(c.getEmployeeCount()); //3
System.out.println(Employee.getEmployeeCount()); //3
```

There is nothing preventing you from making `getEmployeeCount()` non-static. However, because it doesn't matter at all what instance you call the method on (and in fact you don't even really need an instance), it is both convenient and good practice to make the method `static`.

Comment: "By making getEmployeeCount() static, you're saying that not only can any employee call it, the Employee class itself can call the method; you don't need an instance in order to call the method" (Mshnik). Do you mean that static makes a method public instead of private?

Comment: "Because it is only accessing static fields, this makes sense. No matter what instance you were to call it on, it would return the same value" (Mshnik). Do you mean that there are ways to call the instance so that it returns different values? If the employeeCount increases, wouldn't it be necessary and correct to expect an increased value for the accessor method getEmployeeCount?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't matter at all what instance you call the method on (and in fact you don't even really need an instance), it is both convenient and good practice to make the method static."?